# Putting a data-toggle on a select with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

In my Angular program, I want to have an option in my select that brings up a bootstrap modal. Is this possible? Here's how I attempted to do it but nothing pops up.

```html
<select class="form-control" id="empName" [(ngModel)]="selectedEmployee" style="width: 275px;">
          <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UsersModal" value="0">Add New Employee...</option>
          <option disabled>-------</option>
          <option *ngFor="let emp of empInfo; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">{{emp.EmpID}} - {{emp.FirstName}} {{emp.LastName}}</option>
        </select>
        
<div id="UsersModal" class="modal fade" role="form" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <pto-users [selectedEmployee]="selectedEmployee"></pto-users>
</div>
```

Comment: With `data-toggle` probably not, since the `<option>` isn't registering the event.  You could tie a modal trigger into the `<select>` itself though and, based on the value, fire it or not.  This would be via JS though and not data-attributes.

Comment: @RobertC okay, I didn't think so, but I wasn't sure. thanks!